# In hadoop, why does the parquet format occupy higher memory than the original txt when I test?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, orc, sequencefile

I am testing the impact of different data formats on hive query efficiency(win10,only my desktop). The original data is 400 txt files of almost the same size (total memory 169MB). I first converted to orc format (130MB), and then converted from orc format to parquet (423MB) and sequencefile (1.87GB). In my understanding, both parquet and sequencefile formats have some compression features, why does the result occupy higher memory than the original format?

Here is some information that I think is relevant：
**txt**：inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false

**orc**:inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat, compressed:false

**parquet**:inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat, compressed:false

**sequencefile**:inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat, compressed:false

The above information is obtained by "describe extended table_name"
So what happened?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please share how you converted your text files to those format? If you did it by executing some code, please share what the code looks like :)

Comment: Encoding is different. All the outputs here say `compressed:false`, so try setting up snappy compression, at least

Comment: @Koedlt `create table student_tb_orc like student_tb_txt
STORED AS orc;
insert into student_tb_orc
select * from student_tb_txt;
create table if not exists student_tb_par like student_tb_orc STORED as PARQUET;
insert overwrite table student_tb_par
select * from student_tb_orc;` 
other format is converted from orc file